# AWS Lightsail, Windows Server 2016 and SFTP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

We are migrating to / experimenting with AWS. We have chosen Lightsail, as our needs are pretty simple and this seems like a great, simple, affordable option. With that said, we have hit an early roadblock! I cannot figure out how to setup SFTP (or alternatively FTPS) to transfer files to the server?!

FWIW, I am a total AWS newbie. I have searched fairly extensively, and there are troves of information on how to do this on Lightsail w/ Linux, but nothing on Windows.

On our existing infrastructure we simply set up a third party SSH server (it's called Bitvise - FYI), and opened port 22 for it (IP restricted, etc). We can then connect with our FTP client of choice (whether that be FileZilla or our IDEs, etc). However, the same approach did not work on our Lightsail instance (no idea why)!

Does anyone have any idea how to do this? Any assistance is hugely appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest go with the same approach install Bitvise server on windows and run the server . Add the port exception to the windows firewall and security group and access from anywhere.

Comment: @Dan did you find a solution for Lightsail?